# How to use bootstrap grid in angularjs using li and ul tag

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

> `<script> angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) { $scope.names = [ {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'}, {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'}, {name:'Margareth',country:'England'}, {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'}, {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'}, {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'}, {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'}, {name:'Mary',country:'England'}, {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'} ]; }); </script> </head> <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl"> <br><br> <div class="container"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" placeholder="search by universities or states" ng-model="test"> </div> <br><br><br> <div class="container" ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'name'"> <div class="row"> <br> <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'country'|filter:test"> {{ x.name }} </div> <br> </div> </div>`

Comment: Help others reproduce the problem

Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. Here are some guidelines:

Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable

Comment: example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: ok! Sure! I am new to this and i am very fresher.Thanku for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
    <script> 
      angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) { 
               $scope.names = [ 
                  {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'}
                , {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'}
                , {name:'Margareth',country:'England'}
                , {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'}
                , {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'}
                , {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'}
                , {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'}
                , {name:'Mary',country:'England'}
                , {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'} 
             ]; 
          }); 
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <div class="container"> 
      <input type="text" size="40" placeholder="search by universities or states" ng-model="test"> 
    </div> 
    <ul class="container row" style="list-style: none;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;width: 100%;"> 
      <li class="col-md-3" style="float: left;" ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'country'|filter:test">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ x.name }} </li>
    </ul>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanku janani. But i want to use those in grid bootstrap. How to use? Four columns.Col-md-3 is not applying here why?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I have used Grid. See the classes `row col-md-3` used. Check responsive. It works.

Comment: This is how my data looks. Can you suggest for this to display in the grid.                                                                                            WYOMING
Has 1 Universities
University Of Wyoming
Laramie.

Comment: http://www.profileevaluator.com/List-Of-Universities . The format in this link is is what i needed.Any suggessions?

Comment: http://www.profileevaluator.com/List-Of-Universities  . I want this format of diaplaying data. Anyone suggest the code please.

Comment: Which thing you need? The Menus? "Home, About Us, Contact Us"

Comment: The universities list which is displayed in grid format

Comment: for me it looks like this, There are errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyl8nuoqnpiw94n/Desktop%20screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: I did not try but it seems to be closer. But how to get rid of those lines?